# Updating a CLOB XML in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a CLOB column which contains a large amount of XML. I want to add a new attribute in that XML, like this attribute :

```
<name>me</name>
```

I tried using `UpdateXML` but I'm not getting it right.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

`CLOB` is converted to `XMLType` using `XMLType()` and `XMLType` is converted to `CLOB` using `to_clob`. The following is an example.

```
create table table_with_clob (myclob clob);

insert into table_with_clob values ('<mytag><subtag>hello world</subtag></mytag>');

UPDATE table_with_clob SET myclob =
   to_clob(INSERTCHILDXML(xmltype(myclob),
   '/mytag', 'subtag',
   XMLType('<subtag>another</subtag>')));

select * from table_with_clob;
```

Output

```
myclob
------
<mytag><subtag>hello world</subtag><subtag>another</subtag></mytag>
```

Though I think this is not very efficient and you might better convert the column to XMLType and the operate with it.